# XSLT - JSON encode output in Umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco, json

Well hello!

I'm using Umbraco 4 and trying to generate valid JSON. However, my `<xls:value-of />` does not encode my data. I want that, since a ', <, > or \ character simply breaks my JSON.

Is that even possible out of the box?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `xsl:output method="text"`?

Comment: Show us a sample of your input, expected output JSON and your current working style-sheet (what-ever you have so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` when you use `<xsl:value-of/>`.